# d3.rgb().darker/brighter

Tags: colors, internet-explorer-9, d3.js

I'm using d3 to draw a bar chart, where the bars are used to compare different groups (e.g. men/women). For the filling I take a color which is saved in the data file (json) and vary it using `d3.rgb().darker()/.brighter()`.

```
.attr("fill", function(d){return d3.rgb(d.color).darker(1);})
```

It works in Firefox but in Internet Explorer 9 all the bars are shown as black (which is the first used color). I was wondering if this is just an issue with this browser in particular or if I am missing something to avoid this behavior.

One solution would be of course to assign the colors individually, but if possible I'd like to use the provided possibilities.

Comment: If instead of using `d3.rgb` you simply hardcode a color –– like `return #f00;` –– does it show up red in IE9? If not, then that would suggest something else is causing the problem.

Comment: yes, that works as expected, so the problem seems to lie with the darker/brighter-function.

Comment: I'd be pretty surprised if the following makes a difference, but try `return d3.rgb(d.color).darker(1).toString()`. Also, `console.log` the color and see if anything looks odd.

Comment: adding toString() did the trick, thank you.

Answer (score 12):

This happens because you're using `attr("fill")` instead of `style("fill")` to set a style property.

The `style` function includes some additional checking to turn a property value into an appropriate string if needed, so you wouldn't need to do the `toString()` yourself manually.

Changing your original line to:

```
.style("fill", function(d){return d3.rgb(d.color).darker(1);})
```

should work on all browsers including IE.